# Collection fails when using a more restricted admin user

Tags: collection

I have the following collection which helps implement a custom report.

```
<?php


class VMR_Customreports_Model_Resource_Productsordered_Collection
    extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_init('sales/order_item');
    }

    public function setDateRange($from, $to)
    {
        $this->_reset();
        $this->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(
                array('i' => $this->getTable('sales/order_item')),
                'i.`order_id` = main_table.`entity_id`'
            )
            ->where("main_table.created_at BETWEEN '" . $from . "' AND '" . $to . "'")
            ->where('main_table.status != \'canceled\'')
            ->where('main_table.customer_email NOT LIKE \'%@v2cigs.%\'')
            ->where('i.parent_item_id IS NULL')
            ->columns(array(
                'myname' => 'i.name',
                'ordered_qty' => 'sum(i.qty_ordered)',
                'ordered_money' => 'sum(i.`price`*i.qty_ordered)'))
            ->group('i.name');

        return $this;
    }

    public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        if ($storeIds)
            $this->addAttributeToFilter('i.store_id', array('in' => (array)$storeIds));

        return $this;
    }

}
```

When I login as full admin, it selects the right data but when I login as a more restricted user I get an error about, "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous".
I can understand that it's talking about store_id being present both in the order_item table and in the order table, but I am specifying the table to pull from when using `store_id`.

Furthermore, the error happens right at the join.  If I comment out the store_id code I still get the error.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Enterprise Edition, the `AdminGws` module is applying store scope filters so admins are only able to access data they are authorized to see.

Also, you probably want to remove your `__construct()` method. See below for some additional information.

**Background:**

You are extending from `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection`.
This class uses the `sales/order` table (that is, `sales_flat_order` as the main table.

```
 $this->getSelect()->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()));
```

The main table is actually fetched from the associated resource model:

```
public function getMainTable()
{
    if ($this->_mainTable === null) {
        $this->setMainTable($this->getResource()->getMainTable());
    }

    return $this->_mainTable;
}
```

So the resource model is responsible to supply the main table name.
`Mage::getResourceModel($this->getResourceModelName())` is used to collect the resource model.
So what does `getResourceModelName()` return?
It returns the value that was set by the `_init()` call.

```
protected function _init($model, $resourceModel = null)
{
    $this->setModel($model);
    if (is_null($resourceModel)) {
        $resourceModel = $model;
    }
    $this->setResourceModel($resourceModel);
    return $this;
}
```

In your class, you are overriding the `_init()` call of the parent class:

```
$this->_init('sales/order_item');
```

In effect, you are specifying that your collection should use the order item resource model, which will return the table `sales/order_item` as the main table.
Because of your `_init()` call you are joining the `sales_flat_order_item` table with itself.
Fixing that by removing the `_init()` call, or in fact the whole `__construct()` override, will probably fix that issue for you.

Comment: I totally agree with you about the _init() not making sense but it seemed to work with it and I probably got it from some guide somewhere.  But more importantly, even when I comment out the constructor entirely, I still get the store_id error.  And yes I am using the enterprise edition.

Comment: As I've said briefly at the beginning of the post, check the Enterprise_AdminGws module so see which additional filters are added for restricted admin users. You can also turn on logging in *lib/Varien/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php* (set ```$_debug``` and ```$_logAllQueries``` to true) to see the resulting queries.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php since I dont have lib/Varien/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php.  Anyway, when I do that and tail -f my log I dont see anything probably because it recognizes the statement error before it even tries to run it.  I will play with that module to see what I can do.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sure enough I see it adding store_id in a where clause.  How do I make that module use table prefixes?

Comment: I have further confirmed that it is admingws because when I comment out the contents of it's Collection.php's addStoreAttributeToFilter() I see my query without that storeid where clause.  The only problem is, it also fails to load when i do that. :(

Comment: BTW, when I manually add main_table as a prefix, even though execution stops, i dont see errors in the sql log

Answer (score 0):

If I do this:

```
public function addStoreAttributeToFilter($collection)
{
    if($collection->getModelName() == 'sales/order' || $collection->getModelName() == 'sales/order_item')
    {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id', array('in' => $this->_role->getStoreIds()));
    }
    else
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $this->_role->getStoreIds()));
    }
}
```

in AdminGws/Model/Collections.php

and in my collection create a constructor which does $this->_init('sales/order_item') it works.

The constructor part makes no sense to me but I will be asking about that separately.

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced a similar issue. 
Turning on `$_logAllQueries` as @Vinai suggested showed that `Enterprise_AdminGws` was filtering my collection by `store_id`. I fixed it by adding:

```
$collection->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');
```

just before the `$this->setCollection($collection);`